# How to remove an histogram in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am used to work with plots that change over the time in order to show differences when a parameter is changed. Here I provide an easy example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True)

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)

for j in range(1, 15):
    y = np.sin(np.pi*x*j) / (np.pi*x*j)
    line, = ax.plot(x, y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)
    line.remove()
```

You can clearly see that increasing the paramter j the plot becames narrower and narrower.
Now if I want to do the some job with a counter plot than I just have to remove the comma after "line". From my understanding this little modification comes from the fact that the counter plot is not an element of a tuple anymore, but just an attribute as the counter plot completely "fill up" all the space available.

But it looks like there is no way to remove (and plot again) an histogram. Infact if type

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True)

x = np.random.randn(100)

for j in range(15):
    hist, = ax.hist(x, 40)*j
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)
    hist.remove()
```

It doesn't matter whether I type that comma or not, I just get a message of error.
Could you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ax.hist` doesn't return what you think it does.

The returns section of the docstring of `hist` (access via `ax.hist?` in an ipython shell) states:

```
Returns
-------
n : array or list of arrays
    The values of the histogram bins. See **normed** and **weights**
    for a description of the possible semantics. If input **x** is an
    array, then this is an array of length **nbins**. If input is a
    sequence arrays ``[data1, data2,..]``, then this is a list of
    arrays with the values of the histograms for each of the arrays
    in the same order.

bins : array
    The edges of the bins. Length nbins + 1 (nbins left edges and right
    edge of last bin).  Always a single array even when multiple data
    sets are passed in.

patches : list or list of lists
    Silent list of individual patches used to create the histogram
    or list of such list if multiple input datasets.
```

So you need to unpack your output:

```
counts, bins, bars = ax.hist(x, 40)*j
_ = [b.remove() for b in bars]
```

Comment: We are nearly there: if I replace the line "hist.remove()" with something like "p = [b.remove() for b in bars]", than it works without any message of error but only on one loop, that means that I replace "range(1, 15)", with "range(1,2)". But still something has to be changed in order to have it working for a real loop

Comment: @StefanoFedele `ax.hist(...) * j` doesn't make any sense to me. what are you trying to do with that?

Answer (score 2):

Here the right way to iteratively draw and delete histograms in matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True)


for j in range(1, 15):
    x = np.random.randn(100)
    count, bins, bars = ax.hist(x, 40)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(1.5)
    t = [b.remove() for b in bars]
```