# matplotlib.widgets.Slider with histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I'm trying to make the interactive histogram but during

update old histogram is not been cleared, as shown in the image below.

[image])

above plot is generated using following code

```python
from functools import lru_cache
import scipy.stats as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

weight = ss.lognorm(0.23, 0, 70.8)

@lru_cache
def sampling(n):
    return [ weight.rvs().mean() for i in range(1000) ]

theme = {
    'color' : "#1f77b4",
    'alpha' : 0.7,
}

t = ax.hist(sampling(100), **theme)

slider = widgets.Slider(
    ax      = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.03]),
    label   = "n",
    valmin  = 10,
    valmax  = 1000,
    valinit = 100,
    valstep = 1

def update(val):
    global t
    del t
    t = ax.hist(sampling(int(val)), **theme)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

slider.on_changed(update)
ax.set_title('Distribution of Sample Size Mean')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ax.hist is returning a tuple containing the number of bins, the edges of the bins and then the patches... you thus need to capture the patches and remove them in update.

You need to use `t.remove()` in `update`, as in:

```py
*_, patches = ax.hist()

def update(val):
    global patches
    for p in patches:
        p.remove()

    *_, patches = ax.hist(sampling(int(val)), **theme)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Comment: if i do that `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'remove''`, problem is `t` is a tuple and remove is not available.

Comment: haha, my mistake, ax.hist() is returning a tuple, which yeah, is the problem.

Comment: I got the inside scoop it seams. Does the above work for you?

Comment: ya found out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409977/how-to-remove-an-histogram-in-matplotlib i guess yours works too

Comment: shame, looks like this'll be marked as a duplicate I guess. Also You really should turn t into a data class :P

Comment: may be, i was focused on slider thing, totally forgot how hist works!.
hardest part in to name something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214814/discussion-between-andrew-micalled-and-rho).